# Drawing bitmap without scaling on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, screen, android-canvas, scaling

I was trying to drawbitmap on a canvas.  In the emulator, it seems that the image is blurred.  Is it likely that the android automatically scaled the bitmap?  I did try to disable the scaling such as

```
< supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="false" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

blur means if I have a pixel in the bitmap, I am seeing like 2x2 pixel.  soemtimes a pixel is missing.  so I assumed that Android automatically scaled it to fit different screens.  I am just use WVGA and how do I prevent this scaling?  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, both `Bitmap` and `Canvas` have a density property, drawing a bitmap automatically scales the bitmap if the densities of the canvas and bitmap differ.

From [Bitmap.setDensity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setDensity%28int%29) documentation:

> Specifies the density for this bitmap. When the bitmap is drawn to a
>   Canvas that also has a density, it will be scaled appropriately.

You can call `bitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE)` to disable this automatic scaling behavior altogether. If you load the bitmap from resources, placing it under `drawable-nodpi` should be enough.

For the curious: the logic behind this behavior is implemented in `Canvas.cpp` (native part of the `android.graphics.Canvas`), in the `drawBitmap__BitmapFFPaint()` method:

```
static void drawBitmap__BitmapFFPaint(JNIEnv* env, jobject jcanvas,
                                      SkCanvas* canvas, SkBitmap* bitmap,
                                      jfloat left, jfloat top,
                                      SkPaint* paint, jint canvasDensity,
                                      jint screenDensity, jint bitmapDensity) {
    SkScalar left_ = SkFloatToScalar(left);
    SkScalar top_ = SkFloatToScalar(top);

    if (canvasDensity == bitmapDensity || canvasDensity == 0
            || bitmapDensity == 0) {
        if (screenDensity != 0 && screenDensity != bitmapDensity) {
            SkPaint filteredPaint;
            if (paint) {
                filteredPaint = *paint;
            }
            filteredPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            canvas->drawBitmap(*bitmap, left_, top_, &filteredPaint);
        } else {
            canvas->drawBitmap(*bitmap, left_, top_, paint);
        }
    } else {
        canvas->save();
        SkScalar scale = SkFloatToScalar(canvasDensity / (float)bitmapDensity);
        canvas->translate(left_, top_);
        canvas->scale(scale, scale);

        SkPaint filteredPaint;
        if (paint) {
            filteredPaint = *paint;
        }
        filteredPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);

        canvas->drawBitmap(*bitmap, 0, 0, &filteredPaint);

        canvas->restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have lost about two hours trying to figure out what was scaling my bitmaps, and you save my day with that bitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE). Thanks a million. :-)

Comment: You welcome! I've also spent some time in my last project until I realized there's such a feature :)

Comment: I have no idea why but, for me, Bitmap.setDensity was not taken into account until I added <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/> to the manifest...

Answer (score 0):

I think put you bitmap in drawable-nodpi folder will fix this problem.
BTW,  tag only be used by Google Play.