# BlackjackGTV sample - OutOfMemory

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm trying to get the Blackjack Google TV sample working on a Vizio Co-Star (Google TV).  I downloaded the sample code from https://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/ but when I deploy it to the Vizio, I get an OutOfMemory error.

Has anyone gotten the Blackjack GTV sample working?

Full Stack Trace:

04-02 13:32:56.364: E/dalvikvm-heap(4027): Out of memory on a 78655376-byte allocation.
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tv.blackjack/com.google.android.tv.blackjack.BlackJackTableActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class 
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1852)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:124)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class 
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.tv.TvLayoutInflater.onCreateView(TvLayoutInflater.java:50)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:457)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.tv.TvWindow.setContentView(TvWindow.java:248)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1809)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at com.google.android.tv.blackjack.BlackJackTableActivity.onCreate(BlackJackTableActivity.java:58)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4438)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1800)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     ... 11 more
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     ... 23 more
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:604)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:738)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1918)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.View.(View.java:2477)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:379)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:94)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:90)
04-02 13:32:56.374: E/AndroidRuntime(4027):     ... 26 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the layout file and remove the android:background="@drawable/green_background" from the source then it will work for you. There was a memory partition change recently and the sample has not been updated to reduce its memory footprint (eg. Big Bitmap image)

Comment: Thanks...I assumed it was something to do with their images.  Is there documentation on a proper way to use a background image such as that?

Comment: The issue is more about the size of the image used. If you keep the use of big images to a minimum you will be fine. 1920x1080 pixels by 4bytes per pixel + header ~= 8Mb - your application needs to strive to use less then 64Mb or it will run out of memory. The bg image being loaded is 8.3Mb

Comment: Ok, so the memory footprint can't be any larger than normal Android apps...if we wanted a background image like the one in the sample, would it be better to use a smaller image and tile it and apply a gradient after, or just use a lower quality image and stretch it? I assume a stretched image will look far worse on a 46" screen than on a 5" screen...

Comment: You have a few options - you could go to a lower res resource. Or you can try to bypass the scaling step by using a no-scale resource (when android loads images that dont match the view it makes an in memory copy which effectivly doubling the memory footprint) - have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115006/drawing-bitmap-without-scaling-on-android